# Why does reddit use base36 for article id?

Tags: encode

Why does reddit use base36 for article id?

For example:

> a2xki

Answer (score 17):

[Probably because:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36)

> Base 36 is... the most compact
> case-insensitive alphanumeric numeral
> system using ASCII characters

By using only alphanumeric characters and being case-insensitive, two types of errors are dispensed with: input in the wrong case (or filesystem issues and confusion due to case-sensitivity), and special characters in the URL. When a URL has characters that are reserved according to [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), those characters must be escaped (which would elongate and uglify the URL). But various application-level bugs also make use even of *unreserved* characters like `'` and `!` undesirable (some examples: [1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249613) [2](http://drupal.org/node/86166) [3](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-1036)).

Even with the alphanumeric and case-sensitive restrictions, base 36 still provides a much more compact representation than decimal, allowing for short and (arguably) clean-looking IDs.  The ID of [this article](http://www.reddit.com/r/WTF/comments/ln55l/i_thirst_to_purchase_such_a_cat/) would be 36351705 in decimal; it's 3 fewer characters when represented in base 36.

Answer (score 5):

Second Just Some Guy (you can represent with [a-z0-9]), Also,

1. This scheme should produce very short IDs.
2. Easy to use these IDs to create on disk structure.
3. Easy to convert to numeric IDs to look up database, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to give to others in email, verbally, chat windows, etc.  The URL would certainly allow more characters, but this is less confusing, especially if you have to read the link over the phone, in a video, on TV, or even typing it in from a printed article or newspaper.

It's very human friendly.

Comment: It is a number, in base 36.  Why base 36? Because 0..9 + a..z = 36 characters.

Comment: I think there is quite a bit of added value in base 36 for the recognizability of the id.  Instead of looking like another number, which isn't as recognizable, it looks like a (very unique) word, and thus easier to remember.  2342354 vs. as57q (numbers non-randomly chosen for effect)

Comment: It's not a number because base 36 is shorter for the same ID.  A 4 digit base10 number can only represent 10,000 articles while a 4 digit base36 number can represent 1,679,616 articles, and still be just as readable/printable/usable.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can represent it with [a-z0-9], most likely.